# Retagging windows7 to windows-7

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Could we please reverse the synomym for [windows-7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) / [windows7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows7)?

Currently it's [windows-7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) `->` [windows7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows7), if we want to be consistent with the naming it should always have a dash.

Comment: OK, it's now windows7 -> windows-7

Comment: Thank you, Kyle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if we want to be consistent, we should rename it.

We've got things like `macbook-pro`, `ios-appstore`, `system-prefs`, etc.

Worth noting that `windows-7` is already a synonym of `windows7`.

Comment: That's the problem, it should be the other way around.

Comment: Yep. Let's change it.

Comment: Now that you have **the power** could you take care of this?

Comment: @Loic I'm trying, but I hit an error 'Oops, something bad happened.' I'll try again later today.